Punishment regarding murder of a human
There are penances listed in dharmashastras for murder, but are there any laws with capital punishment or some other government penalty for murderers to face?

The daṇḍa varies on the jāti of the murderer and that of the victim, it's not the same for everyone, furthermore there are several other factors that are to be taken in consideration by the one who holds the daṇḍa in his hands. He needs to assess the aparādha in its entirety, in what situation the murder happened, and so on. For e.g. if the murder happened purely because the murderer was defending him/her self from harm, the murderer may not be daṇḍita. Also, the instigator of murder may be daṇḍita as well. So, daṇḍanīti is extremely comprehensive and a detailed affair.

Also, the Rājā may take the decision of awarding a lighter daṇḍa than the one that the aparādhin may deserve by theory. For e.g. if by theory, there is the vidhāna of mṛtyudaṇḍa, instead of death, one may give the daṇḍa of mutilation of some limbs. It's severe, but less harsh than death punishment, and both daṇḍas often appear as vikalpas, as per smṛtis and nibandhas. But still, the Rājā cannot be generous beyond the niyamas of daṇḍanīti. Generosity should be extended within the framework of niyamas only.

The most serious of all murders (of manuṣyas) is the murder of a Brāhmaṇa, and it has the harshest punishment, death penalty for Kṣatriya, etc. who commits such a murder. But in old Bhārata (pre-Izlamic), few would even dare (or even wish) to slay Brāhmaṇas.

@Bingming interesting what about for a shudra what is the danda?

I heard there is a penance which is there similair to killing an animal, but what of capital punishment?
